# Show info about used compiler in maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, maven-3, tycho, eclipse-jdt, maven-compiler-plugin

I am using Maven with Eclipse compiler. Here is the configuration:

```
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1</version>
           <configuration>
              <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
              <skipMain>${skip.sources.compilation.with.javac}</skipMain>
              <skip>${skip.test.sources.compilation.with.javac}</skip>
              <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
              <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
              <source>${compiler.level}</source>
              <target>${compiler.level}</target>
              <optimize>${compiler.optimize}</optimize>
              <debug>${compiler.debug}</debug>
              <debuglevel>${compiler.debug.level}</debuglevel>
              <meminitial>512m</meminitial>
              <maxmem>1024m</maxmem>
              <compilerArgs>
                 <arg>-showversion</arg>
              </compilerArgs>
              <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
           </configuration>
           <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                 <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
                 <version>0.22.0</version>
              </dependency>
           </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I want to print information about currently used compiler, because 'compilerId' tag sometimes can be removed from configuration.
For these purposes I've added:

```
              <compilerArgs>
                 <arg>-showversion</arg>
              </compilerArgs>
```

... as on example above.

But it is not working...

> [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ MvnExample --- 
>   [INFO] Compiling 12 source files to C:\Java\MvnExample\target\classes

Have you any ideas about how to achieve it?

Comment: The maven-compiler-plugin parses output from the actual compiler to show you the progress/results, but it doesn't print it out directly to maven build log. You will have to find a different way of doing that. Is there perhaps some argument that is JDT-specific and will make other compilers fail due to unknown argument?

Comment: Alternatively you can set verbose=true, in which case build output will include a lot more than you probably want, but it should also include the compiler being used.

Comment: Thank you, but 'verbose' is not acceptable for me. Looks like I need some of available plugins (e.g 'echo-plugin') to print message about used compiler...